# Fresh Project With CallNtPowerInformation From PowrProf.h Having Linker Errors

Tags: c++, winapi, linker-errors

I just created a new project (Win32 Console Application) in visual studio 2017 RC, and coded this, that, as far as my understanding goes, should be working.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "PowrProf.h Or Powerbase.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY PowerPlugged;
    SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY PowerUnPlugged;
    POWER_ACTION_POLICY ActionPlugged;
    POWER_ACTION_POLICY ActionUnPlugged;
    CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc, NULL, 0, &PowerPlugged, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY));
    CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyDc, NULL, 0, &PowerUnPlugged, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY));
    ActionPlugged.Action = PowerActionNone;
    ActionUnPlugged.Action = PowerActionNone;
    PowerPlugged.LidClose = ActionPlugged;
    PowerUnPlugged.LidClose = ActionUnPlugged;
    CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc, &PowerPlugged, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY), NULL, 0);
    CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyDc, &PowerUnPlugged, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY), NULL, 0);

    string yaes;
    getline(cin, yaes);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I really never had to deal with the Linker, and the code gives me no errors. Except for when building of course.

The remarks section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675(v=vs.85).aspx) says nothing about this.

I am on windows 10 and I've tried including Powerbase.h, PowrProf.h. Both gave me the exact same errors:

> LNK2019:  unresolved external symbol _CallNtPowerInformation@20
>   referenced in function
>   _main BatterySettings c:\Users\badmouthing\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\BatterySettings\BatterySettings\BatterySettings.obj

And of course

> LNK1120   1 unresolved externals  BatterySettings c:\users\profanity(I'm
>   just having fun, the username is the same)\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\BatterySettings\Debug\BatterySettings.exe

So what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include PowrProf.h try doing it like this

```
extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>

}
#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")
```

If that is not it, have you tried doing a clean rebuild?

Comment: Worked. Would you mind explaining how/why?

Comment: @ninjaiceflame - you use [`CallNtPowerInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675(v=vs.85).aspx) - so it must be implemented somewhere. if you read documentation - it implemented in `PowrProf.dll` - so you need link with `PowrProf.lib`

Comment: @RbMm Got that part, What I don't understand is what `extern "c"` is for. I tried not using it and it worked.

Comment: @TrisT: It tells the compiler to use C [linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) (vs. the standard C++ linkage when compiling C++). You don't need it, because the Windows API headers already specify C linkage throughout. That's what you get for [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).